# okta-token-storage is empty after having previously worked for authorization

Tags: reactjs, okta

I am currently implementing Okta authentication/authorization in a create-react-app. I followed instructions on [1](https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react_sign-in_widget) and had been able to login and verify that that okta-token-storage contained information on the user group. While working today, something broke. When I log in I see this in the developer tools in chrome [a picture showing that okta-token-storage was completely empty, while okta-cache-storage contains information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqrkq.png).

I have reinstalled @okta/okta-signin-widget, @okta/okta-react and react-router-dom but to no avail. I also have tried creating a new application in the Okta developer dashboard and used that ClientID and that does not work. I also created a new react app and followed the aforementioned blog [1](https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react_sign-in_widget) and was successfully able to sign in the simple example and view the protected page.

I am hoping to find a fix without having to rebuild the app from scratch. Has anyone at Okta seen this happen before? I am new to working in React...

Thanks!